# Initialize audio wav file object from path or url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, audio

I have audio wav file on my server, I wanted to send this file api but I am not able to get how Initialize audio wav file object from path or url.

Here is the code i am using 
var file = new File("", "1.wav", {type:"audio/x-wav", lastModified: new Date().getTime()});

but it is Initializing file with size 0.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you need a File?

Answer (score 0):

You can request the file from server as a `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer`, then pass the response to `File` constructor. Note,  the first argument to [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) constructor should be an array, not a string

```
fetch("1.wav")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  let file = new File([blob], "1.wav", {
               type:"audio/x-wav", lastModified:new Date().getTime()
             });
  // do stuff with `file`
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thank you very much..Work perfect !!